# toggle working for first and last toggle calls

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to set a series of toggle events.  For some reason only the first toggle for PreAuth and last toggle for Refund work as in it toggles just fine, it expands/contracts my options div.

But the 3 in the middle, while seemingly almost the same type of call do not. For the 3 in the middle, when I click the hyperlink that triggers the onclick, it appears to try or at least do it very fast (expands then retracts again).  It doesn't stay expanded like the first and last if I click the hyperlink (hyperlink is the "option" DOM element

Here are the hyperlinks before clicked

[image]

I click for example PreAuth and it expands as expected:

[image]

When I click Void, Delay Capture, or Capture hyperlinks I see a very quick flinch as if it tried to do something.  I think what it's doing is expanding and collapsing very fast...doesn't stay open.

Here's the code:

```
$(function ()
{
    setEvents();

    hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();



    function setEvents()
    {
        $('#pOption').click(function(){
                                                        toggleElementWithEffect('pContent', 'slow');
                                                        if ($("#txt_Pre_MReference")) { $("#txt_Pre_Reference").val(new Date().getTime()); }
                                                        return false;
                                                     });

        $('#cOption').click(function(){ toggleElementWithEffect('cContent', 'slow')});
        $('#dCaptureOption').click(function(){ toggleElementWithEffect('dCaptureContent', 'slow')});
        $('#vOption').click(function(){ toggleElementWithEffect('vContent', 'slow')});
        $('#rOption').click(function(){
                                                toggleElementWithEffect('rContent', 'slow');
                                                if ($("#txt_Refund_MReference")) { $("#txt_R_Reference").val(new Date().getTime()); }
                                                return false;
                                            });
    }
```

});

Comment: need .. to .. kill .. urge to .. indent .. code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably missing this on the others:

```
return false;
```

Since they are links.

**Edit**

But, as mentioned in the comments, this should be used instead:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Comment: I also see the error in FireBug of SyntaxError: SyntaxError: Using //@ to indicate source map URL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead
 

/*! jQuery v2.0.2 | (c) 2005, 2013 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/license

Comment: I'm referencing jQuery as so:  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>

Comment: return false is bad practice.  All I need is just event.preventDefault();

Answer (score 0):

As he said you are missing a **semicolon ';'** and `return false`

http://jsfiddle.net/zRJ63/10/

Comment: I just needed event.preventDefault();